# Fetch fails when exceeding a certain execution time even-though using proper CORS headers

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have been stuck with a weird issue with CORS for quite some time now. To explain the setup I have a frontend JS snippet (including fetch API call to my own server) which I want to use as an embed code snippet other web applications can use. (ex: kind of like google analytics)

```
// JS snippet to copy to an unknown website 

<script>
// extract data and add to the body
const extracted_data = {}

fetch("https://api.xxxx.com/xxxxxx/create", {
        method: "POST",
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(extracted_data),
        referrer: "origin",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            // The API call was successful!
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            // This is the JSON from our response
            console.warn("Successfull!", data);
            alert("Success:" + JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // There was an error
            console.warn("Something went wrong ->", err);
            alert("error:" + err.message);
        });

</script>
```

[image]

The problem is even if I have set my fetch API as below and the correct CORS headers are in my preflight response from my API it works only when the API call resolves immediately. If the API takes more time Fetch throws this common error even if the preflight is successful.

`TypeError: Failed to fetch`

I verified it using adding the below code to my API. Then it stops working and throws the above error. When I don't have any time taking functions inside my API call it works without errors.

```
 // 10 sec delay to check async behavior of the API
 await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
```

Any recommendations on how I should proceed to resolve this?

Comment: does this happen in all browsers, or just the one you're using?

Comment: it would be useful to compose the fetch's options   beforehand.

Comment: server may have a short timeout. I've seen some node.js setups that kill connections that last longer than 10 seconds

Comment: @MisterJojo can you elaborate a bit more on what you meant by "compose the fetch's options beforehand"?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I was trying to figure it out from that side, but the thing is the endpoint works fine when we use postman or something external but only does not work using the browser to do the API call. Do you think it can be an issue with the server?

Comment: What is "takes more time"? 5 seconds, 3 hours?

Comment: And why exactly does the request fail? "TypeError: Failed to fetch" doesn't tell us much. How is the delayed response different?

Comment: simply create a variable containing your calculated options, rather than doing this calculation in the fetch, and thus extracting this calculation time out of the execution of the fetch. I will do the same for your 2 alerts.

Comment: @epascarello in this case, I put a timeout of 10s inside the API removing all other code and it doesn't work. But when I remove the timeout and hardcode the response it works

Comment: @JaromandaX it is there in other browsers as well. ex: in Safari the error says ```Load Failed```  but it's same behavior

Comment: Are you sure it is not the issue with the backend code? Show what causes the issue.

Comment: @AselaWijesinghe you mention safari, so this is an apple device - what happens on non apple devices

Comment: @AselaWijesinghe POSTMAN and other solutions don't send OPTIONS. They just hit the GET or POST endpoint. If the OPTIONS endpoint is timing out, that's a problem.

Comment: but I have definitely seen Chrome report a CORS problem, when really it was a 404 error or 502 error, since the error messages don't include the cors headers sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my colleague found the reason behind this fetch not working under the asynchronous behavior issue. But I still don't know why it behaves that way but when we attach a `async` function to a button listener it doesn't work as expected (I verified that with alerts as well in the answer the 2nd alert doesn't trigger).

```
async triggerFetch(){
//same function posted in the question with fetch
}

async function handleButtonClick() {
    alert("Alert 1 - Start with fetch");
    await TriggerFetch();
    alert("Alert 2 - Done with fetch");
}


async function initButtonListener() {
    if (document.getElementById("btn_send_ahead")) {
        var nextBtn = document.getElementById("btn_send_ahead");
        nextBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            await handleButtonClick();
        });
    } else {
    // since button is not rendered initially will have to retry until its available
        window.setTimeout("initButtonListener()", 10);
    }
}

initButtonListener();
```

But the unspoken part of this question is what happens to the behavior of the specific web application when attaching a button listener. When we click the web application button, it reloads the page with some internal action, so my script doesn't execute fully. Maybe with a `race condition` issue with existing behavior. when you look at it in that way it makes sense why the fetch didn't work when it takes more time. But the fetch is working if we use it like this.

```
async function initButtonListener() {
    if (document.getElementById("btn_send_ahead")) {
        var nextBtn = document.getElementById("btn_send_ahead");
        // nextBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
         //   await handleButtonClick();
       // });

       //no button listener just call the script when page is loaded
       await TriggerFetch(sample_payload);
    } else {
    // since button is not rendered initially will have to retry until its available
        window.setTimeout("initButtonListener()", 10);
    }
}

initButtonListener();
```